# differences among numpy array types

Tags: numpy

Is there a good overview of the different types of arrays in NumPy? For instance, I gather that there are structured arrays, record arrays (in some places they are used synonymously and in others they are said to be different, esp. since there is a recarray submodule which seems to be different from the usual structured arrays), arrays with records that can be indexed by name (not just the fields), and a DataFrame class on the Python Cookbook site; also masked arrays... Are these completely separate from ndarrays or is there some inheritance connecting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nearest I've seen to such an overview is this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html

Comment: Thanks, yes - this is helpful. Unfortunately it mostly lists them rather than discussing when each would be appropriate. But is still helpful.